# Google Maps Javascript API - Conditional Markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I am currently working on a web app that allows users to locate nearby cafes. I am in the process of adding in functionality that lets the user know whether the cafe is open or closed and have successfully added this information so that it appears in the infowindow.

For better user experience I would also like to set the map up so that the color of the marker changes depending on the open status of the cafe. Green marker = open and red marker = closed

Here is the current script I have put together for the markers/infowindow details

```
function createMarker(place) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: 'img/greenmarker.svg',
        position: place.geometry.location
    });
    var request = {
        reference: place.reference
    };
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        service.getDetails(request, function (place, status) {
            var open;
            if (place.opening_hours.open_now === true) {
                open = "We are Open";
            } else {
                open = "We are Closed";
            };
            if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                var contentStr = '<h5>' + place.name + '</h5><p>' + place.formatted_address;
                if (!!place.opening_hours)
                    contentStr += '<br>' + open;
                console.log(place);
                if (!!place.formatted_phone_number)
                    contentStr += '<br>' + place.formatted_phone_number;
                if (!!place.website)
                    contentStr += '<br><a target="_blank" href="' + place.website + '">' + place.website + '</a></p>';

                infoWindow.setContent(contentStr);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            } else {
                var contentStr = "<h5>No Result, status=" + status + "</h5>";
                infoWindow.setContent(contentStr);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

I have tried adding in the specific marker svgs into the conditional statement, but this didn't seem to work

```
var marker;
        var request = {
            reference: place.reference
        };

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            service.getDetails(request, function (place, status) {
                var open;
                if (place.opening_hours.open_now === true) {
                    open = "We are Open";
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        icon: 'img/greenmarker.svg',
                        position: place.geometry.location
                    });
                } else {
                    open = "We are Closed";
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        icon: 'img/redmarker.svg',
                        position: place.geometry.location
                    });
                };
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you only want to change the marker colour when the user clicks on it?

Comment: What doesn't work exactly?

Comment: @duncan no, I would like the marker colour to change based on opening hours information retrieved from the google places API

Comment: What's the `place` object you're passing into the `createMarker` function?

Comment: The first parameter to the PlacesService `getDetails` function is a [PlaceDetailsRequest](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#PlaceDetailsRequest) which has a single `placeId` property. You're using a `reference` property instead.

Comment: ... I'm assuming that the `service` is an instance of the PlacesService of course, which maybe it isn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, here's a more or less working version of what you're attempting.  You'd need to call the `createMarker` function several times with different placeIds

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<style type="text/css">
html { height: 100% }
body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
#map { width:100%; height:90% }
</style>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>

<script>
    var service, map;

    function initialize() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
            zoom: 17,
            center: {lat: -33.866651, lng: 151.195827},
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

        createMarker('ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4');
    }

    function createMarker(placeId) {
        var request = {
            placeId: placeId
        };

        service.getDetails(request, function (place, status) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/green.png',
                position: place.geometry.location
            });

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: ''
            });

            if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                var contentStr = '<h5>' + place.name + '</h5><p>' + place.formatted_address;

                var open = "We are ";
                if (place.opening_hours.open_now) {
                    open += "Open";
                } else {
                    open += "Closed";
                    marker.setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/red.png');
                }

                if (!!place.opening_hours) {
                    contentStr += '<br>' + open;
                }
                if (!!place.formatted_phone_number) {
                    contentStr += '<br>' + place.formatted_phone_number;
                }
                if (!!place.website) {
                    contentStr += '<br><a target="_blank" href="' + place.website + '">' + place.website + '</a></p>';
                }
            } else {
                var contentStr = "<h5>No Result, status=" + status + "</h5>";
            }

            setupInfowindow(marker, infowindow, contentStr);
        });
    }

    function setupInfowindow(marker, infoWindow, contentStr) {
        marker.addListener('click', function () {
            infoWindow.setContent(contentStr);
            infoWindow.open(map, this);
        });
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```